# Orders collection - how to get all in the time range (current day)

Tags: magento-1.9, order-totals, order-collection

Trying to gather all the orders (current day) and sum totals

Updated:

```
    $format = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y/m/d');
    $from = $format.' 00:00:00';
    $now  = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y/m/d H:m:i');

    $torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addFieldToFilter('state',Array('neq'=>Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from,'to' => $now))
        ;
```

everything is fine except one little thing, one of the orders seems to be not in collection.

Checked all `customer_emails` and the order created just before midnight (00:14:46) is not included in **collection** for some reason.
suppose to be 127 order while `getSize()` is saying 126 regardless what filters used etc.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$from = new DateTime('2017-08-29 00:00:00');
$from = $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$to = new DateTime('2017-08-29 23:59:9');
$to = $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW));
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: Yur code does exactly the same thing. Still one order is missing for some unknown reason. The only difference is that the missing order was created at 00:14:46 while all the res was created after 06:30:00 ..... why it won't get this one (from 00:14:46)?

Comment: Change $from to '2017-08-29 00:00:01' and if it don't work, can you please edit your post with details of the order created at 00:14:46? I'm assuming it has something to do with it.

Comment: Ok, good idea,checking :)
Nope, same ;( I can't see anything what can cause this issue but to be honest I was testing script on local server where all the orders had the same statuses etc and there was still problem with number of orders, always was -1.

Comment: Update created_at from one of today's orders at table sales_flat_order to '2017-08-29 00:13:00' and see if you can see that order with your code

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Hello S, seems like today everything is perfectly fine, new orders comming and it counts correctly. But still don't know what was the issue.

Comment: Nice to know that it works fine now. Probably, as we discussed, it had something to do with that specific order.

Comment: Nope, same today, one order created at 00:10:13 .... skipped and wont be displayed on my orders list ;(

Comment: Oh, too bad :( I really don't know what is causing this, so feel free to unmark my answer

Comment: Hi, no worries, will not unmark because th code is working but this behaviour si strange. Assuming that this is the problem related to the time zone conversion or something. Why only orders created within first hour of the day won't work ?

Comment: I can't really think of anything other than time zone differences. But that would still not make much sense, because you would be able to see today's order at yesterday report. Can you please try to filter yesterday's orders and see if it appears?

Comment: I'll try :) now ;)

Comment: It must be related to the "created_at". Every day checking list of orders and it seems if order was created between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00 script won't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi make sure pass proper time as well in from and to check below Idea.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$from   = date($format)." 00:00:00";
$to     = date($format)." 23:59:59";;
```

Comment: This is exactly (almost) as I did but this is not an issue.
  $brom = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y/m/d');
  $from = $brom.' 00:00:00';
  $now  = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y/m/d H:m:i');
Doing exactly what your code does :)

Comment: May be order is in "new" state

Comment: Nope, checked it, tried also select only with state NEW. Nothing! :(
I think I know, server time ...... this might be an issue ..... or ..... maybe not ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
<?php
$from_date  = new DateTime('2017-08-17 00:00:00');
$from_date = $from_date ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$to_date = new DateTime('2017-08-29 23:59:9');
$to_date = $to_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($orders->getData());
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but: first it must be only for one day range from 00:00:00 up tp 23:59:59 andsecondly: the code is exactly the same :)

Comment: Seems like it still not working properly if order was created near midnight for some reason, Tonight one of the orders was created at 00:10:13 and script just want see it.